# mysql password() encrypted password to oracle migration

Tags: php, mysql, database, oracle, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL password function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751152/mysql-password-function)

I am making tables for my homepage's registration fields using MySQL.

I googled the way for encrypting passwords and it showed me that I can use password() on MySQL query for the encryption.

The problem is, when I change my database system like MySQL -> Oracle, can I migrate my database and the encrypted keys?

Is it okay that I use just password() without any worries?

Thanks in advance

ps. I apologize that I didn't bring any source code but I don't know even it will work or not.

Comment: You should use bcrypt or scrypt or PBKDFv2, not `password()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1751262/34397

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take a look at [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) on how to store passwords in a DB. Basically you should used something like [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) to hash the passwords before storing them. These schemes are not only very secure, but are also DBMS-agnostic, so you don't have to worry about any DBMS migration issues.