# CakePHP - how to use MySQL function password()

Tags: cakephp, passwords

Everyone.

I have been trying to create user info saving process, and bumped into this issue.
I wanted to use mysql function password() for password field, but seems no way to use MySQL function when to save data.

Is there any way to do this or simply it s impossible in CakePHP?

Thank you.

Comment: ["The `PASSWORD()` function is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you should *not* use it in your own applications."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password)

Comment: Well..I should not use it... if use, something happen? Also no matter should use or not, can you give the right answer regarding CakePHP thing?

Comment: It's just that it's not very secure. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751152/mysql-password-function. It's much better to use the password hashing capabilities CakePHP offers instead of bypassing them and using MySQL's insecure method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:**

```
$this->data['MyModel']['password'] = 
    DboSource::expression('PASSWORD('.$password.')');
```

**More Details:**

I agree with the commenter that it's not ideal to do what you're asking, but if you really want to, you CAN run a regular MySQL query directly with the `query()` method. More info here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query

Example:

```
$this->Picture->query("SELECT * FROM pictures LIMIT 2;");
```

Or use the method mentioned above in the "TLDR" which allows you to use MySQL functions to process your data.

**Different (but recommended) method:**

Here is the documentation on how to hash your password the CakePHP way:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords

Comment: So... no way to use mysql function when to save data? I mean when to use $this->Model->save($save_data)

Comment: Glad it helped!  Cleaned up a bit now that I know it's what you were looking for.