# mysql_real_escape_string() and password() issues

Tags: php, mysql, sql, basic-authentication

Hi i'm just wondering if this is possible

```
$pass_esc = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
$user_esc = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
$query = "UPDATE users SET user_password = PASSWORD('$pass_esc') WHERE user_name = '$user_esc'";
```

I don't know if its just me or it is really not possible because everytime i use this i get an error and if i use this

```
$pass_esc = $pass;
$user_esc = $user;
$query = "UPDATE users SET user_password = PASSWORD('$pass') WHERE user_name = '$user_esc'";
```

it's fine on my end.

Comment: what is the main issue?

Comment: What does it mean "I get an error"

Comment: there might be single quote or special chars in either $pass or $user, suggest to echo both out to check.

Comment: execute manually your final query in phpmyadmin or any tool that you use. you will get the error.

Comment: the main issue is, can i use mysql_real_escape_string and password() at the same time? because everytime i use them both i get this Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO).

but when i don't i dont get any error

Comment: Your main problem is you have limited access to your mysql connection, you have core problem with mysql_connect(). However, check this out regarding PASSWORD() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751152/mysql-password-function

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put $.

Old query.

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET user_password = PASSWORD('$pass_esc') WHERE user_name = 'user_esc'";
```

New query:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET user_password = PASSWORD('$pass_esc') WHERE user_name = '$user_esc'";
```

Comment: oka, guys, second answer about the `$`. How does it make an error? If the string `'user_esc'` is not contained in column `user_name` it will not get an error, but will have affected_rows = 0

Comment: dont mind the variables coz it is supposed to be a typo, you get the idea if you really understand what mysql_real_escape_string on php and password() on sql

Comment: @A Super Awesome. You didn't defined what's the error. May be if record is not updating, you consider it an error.