# Trying to retrieve password from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck on a problem with my login script that it will not successfully pull the password data from the sql statement I give it.

The user is asked to enter their email & password,

```
<p><strong>Email: </strong><input type= "text" name= "email"></p>
<p><strong>Password: </strong><input type= "password" name= "password"></p>
```

Through POST, I take what they typed from the form and put it into a sql statement.

```
$taremail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$tarpasswd = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');

$sql = "SELECT email, password FROM members WHERE email = '".$taremail."'
        AND password = PASSWORD('".$tarpasswd."')";
```

Finally, I check against the database to see if that email and password they typed in is actually in the database.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){

    setcookie("auth", "1", time()+60*30, "/", "", 0); //create cookie for the logged in user    

    $display = "<h2>You have successfully logged in!</h2>
                <p>Click the link below to go to our main page</p>
                <a href=\"main.php\">Main Page</a></br>
                <a href=\"../login.html\">Log out</a>";
} else {
    $display = "<h2>This account is not registered!</br>
                Please make sure to register before trying to log in.</h2>
                <a href=\"../register.html\">Register here!</a>
                <a href=\"../login.html\">Login page</a>";
}
```

This either returns that the email and password given is indeed in the database or it's not. Simple enough right?

My problem is that it always executes my `else{}` statement, saying that I have not registered.

I should note that in my registration page, the password they give is put through the `PASSWORD()` method, so it becomes a hashed varchar on the database... Ex. letmein = *D37C49F9CBEFBF8B6F4

Comment: First change `== 1` to `> 0`.

Comment: NO, I don't think it's encrypted rather it's hashed and so can't be decrypt.

Comment: Can you verify a record exist for that email?

Comment: Using phpmyadmin? I have the table open right now with 3 different values in it. When I register a user, it is updated into the database as well. @kdogisthebest

Comment: Ok in your PHP code `echo $sql`. Then run that in phpMyAdmin and see what it says.

Comment: You're saying the value of the password field in the database is not the actual password, it is a hashed version?

Comment: Correct @JamesTrudeau

Comment: You should also echo `$tarpasswd` & `$taremail` to test if those are correct

Comment: when I `echo $sql` it returns with this: `SELECT email, password FROM members WHERE email = 'test@gmail.com' AND password = PASSWORD('letmein')` This is the correct input I gave to the text fields on my form, but it's not hashing it... right?

Comment: You may want to read this Q&A's on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/1751152/ regarding MySQL's `PASSWORD()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was running tests on something I set up for this, and I think I found the problem.  This was frustrating.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-hashing.html

From the docs on the PASSWORD() function:

"To accommodate longer password hashes, the Password column in the user table was changed at this point to be 41 bytes, its current length."

My password field in my user column was only storing 25 bytes, so a PASSWORD() of my fake password 'asdfasdf' was yielding "*1B1A59A0792309FDE6F1A8681D2B58C4F2639156", but my table was only storing "*1B1A59A0792309FDE6F1A868" due to the lack of storage space.

I'm sure you can guess the result of comparing those two.

This may not be your problem but it could help some other poor, broken individual in the future.

Comment: hmmm... So I'd assume varchar(20) is much too small if i'm going to be hashing it?

Comment: yes that's going to be an issue, fortunately it's not difficult to edit the max varchar length.  Just increase it to something like 50.  The only issue is all of your current stored passwords are essentially junk and will have to be fixed, as they are truncated and will never compare properly to the output of the PASSWORD() function.

Comment: Absolutely. I changed my structure of my password column from varchar(20) -> (50). Created a new user, logged in and success!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

If the `PASSWORD` php function then call this function in query following way.

```
$sql = "SELECT email, password FROM members WHERE email = '".$taremail."'
        AND password = PASSWORD('$tarpasswd')";
```

Comment: **Fatal error: Call to undefined function PASSWORD()** is what I get when I try to use that in my query

Comment: check in you registration page code..where to call this function and encrypt password to hase??

Comment: `mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO members (firstname, lastname, email, password) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', PASSWORD('$passwd'))");` This is how it's called in my register code.

Comment: ohk..`PASSWORD` is my sql function and it will work in query!!..Check edited answer..??is this helped??

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It still returns just the password... not the hashed version. `SELECT email, password FROM members WHERE email = 'test@gmail.com' AND password = PASSWORD('letmein')` That's the output when I `echo $sql`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65885/discussion-between-kupendra-and-almorrow).