# Simple mysql syntax error in PASSWORD() function

Tags: mysql

I'll say hello to the senior developers first.

Excuse my poor English.

Development Environment : ubuntu 16.04.1 - MYSQL 5.7.21

I used the following query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
from user_info 
where user_id= 'myid' and user_pw=PASSWORD('mypassword');
```

**There is no problem with operation, but the following warnings are given.**

I checked the warning and it said it was a syntax error.

**I think it is a query that is not problematic at all, but I wonder why it sends a warning.**

Please remind me if you know any senior developers.

p.s I attach a picture just in case.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1751262/3179169. It says don't use `PASSWORD` function.

Comment: See [PASSWORD() :: 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password): `This function is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.6 and will be removed in a future MySQL release.` and [PASSWORD() :: 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password): `This function was removed in MySQL 8.0.11.`, that causes the warning. The error is caused by the syntax problem (`show warning\g`), not by the PASSWORD function.